# sum aggregation not working for duplicate data elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sum, aggregation

For example, my mapping has one property "itemDetails", like this

```
{
  "properties":{
    "itemDetails":{
      "properties":{
        "id1":{"type": "long"},
        "iddetailCode1": {"type": "string"},
        "id2":{"type": "long"},
        "iddetailCode2": {"type": "string"},
        "amount": {"type": "double"}
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

and for one item, it has multiple records. I want to group by iddetailCode1, and sum up all the amount. However, if two rocords has the same amount, it only be calculated once, I could not get the correct data.

my query is like this.

```
{
    "aggs": {
    "user_likes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "itemDetails.entityDetailCode1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "likes_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "itemDetails.amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Terms aggregations create one bucket per unique value, and the counts in these buckets are not 100% accurate. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks Gavin, yes, this is why finally I am using nested aggregation which could give us the accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have the solution, in this case, when put the mapping, we have to change the datatype of "itemDetails" to "nested". "The nested type is a specialised version of the object datatype that allows arrays of objects to be indexed and queried independently of each other". 
mapping should be:

```
{
  "properties":{
    "itemDetails":{
      "type": "nested",
      "properties":{
        "id1":{"type": "long"},
        "iddetailCode1": {"type": "string"},
        "id2":{"type": "long"},
        "iddetailCode2": {"type": "string"},
        "amount": {"type": "double"}
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

and query should be

```
{
"aggs": {
    "nestedName": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "itemDetails"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Groupby": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "itemDetails.iddetailCode1",
            "size": 50
          },
          "aggs": {
            "amount": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "itemDetails.amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```